# Xcode 6.1 Source Control "Unable to load revisions"

Tags: xcode6, revision-history

I've been using the source control with Xcode for years but when I tried to pull up the history today it simply states that it is "Unable to load revisions"

Any idea how to retrive the history and/or put the project version control back on track?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I ran into this problem and found a solution. My issue was that ~/.config was owned by the system instead of me. Related to this solution:

[Unable to access 'git/attributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes/47995027)

Here's how to change file ownership in finder on Mac OS:

http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/23/change-file-ownership-mac-os-x/