# Unable to access 'git/attributes'

Tags: git

What does warning `remote: warning: unable to access '/root/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied` means and what implications does it bring?

```
$git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/egit/egit.git
Cloning into 'egit'...
remote: warning: unable to access '/root/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
remote: Counting objects: 57926, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11872/11872), done.
remote: Total 57926 (delta 30734), reused 56308 (delta 29136)
Receiving objects: 100% (57926/57926), 32.29 MiB | 1021 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (30734/30734), done.
Checking out files: 100% (1483/1483), done.
```

Should I report potential infrastructure problem to hoster?

Answer (score 267):

I ran into this situation myself. After verifying that it was looking in `~/.config/` I noticed the owner of that folder was `root`. I changed this to `my_user_name` and it worked.

```
cd ~/
ls -al
<Noticed .config was owned by root, unlike everything else in $HOME>
sudo chown -R $(whoami) .config
```

It helps to know the cause as well: This directory is created the first time you run a program that uses it. If the command was run as `root`, it will cause this permissions problem.

For example, if the `~/.config` directory does not yet exist, and you run `sudo htop`, the directories `~/.config` and `~/.config/htop` will be created and owned by `root`. Afterward, a regular git command wont be able to access `~/.config` and will give the above warning. (Credit: user [@krethika](/users/1235982))

The `-R` option with `chown` is to modify the permissions recursively. This will help if you have subfolders under `~/.config`

Comment: that also helped me while using linux command line inside windows 10 - thank You!

Comment: Mine had subdirectories, so I had to add `-R` option to chown recursively.

Comment: I ran into this problem just following the getting started Amazon's Lightsail node docs and this solved it perfectly, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot @BlackVegetable for this help. It helped me too. Since, I didn't have subdirectories, so I removed `-R` while changing ownership.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Should you also specify the group with something like `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) .config` ?

Comment: I guess ppl will find this thread after installing `htop`. « htop requires root privileges to correctly display all running processes, so you will need to run `sudo htop`. » The `~/.config` dir is created at the first `htop` launch only. Be sure to run `htop` without sudo the first time so the `~/.config` dir is created with user ownership.

Comment: running `sudo htop` is precisely how I ended up here

Answer (score 12):

I think your `HOME` envireonment variable is improperly set.

From the [google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlist/FB8DQhTZtQY),

> the HOME environment variable was set to `/root` so it looked at `/root/.gitconfig` or `/root/.config/git/config` since the unprivileged user didn't have access to `/root` it threw an error.
>
> So the solution was for me to set the HOME env to the user's HOME directory

Answer (score 8):

Go to root directory

`cd ~/`

Write the following code:

`sudo chown -R username /Users/username`

Where username is your system's username.

Comment: This answer to "Should i change .config folder ownership that is in my own home directory? " is relevant. 


https://askubuntu.com/questions/852265/should-i-change-config-folder-ownership-that-is-in-my-own-home-directory-why-i

Answer (score 3):

Git is trying to read config from root instead of user config. Please check your environment variables have the correct git config set or the .gitconfig file in your home folder is accessible.

Comment: Are there any potential problems caused by this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your user's privileges. You have to give yourself root privileges.

You can fix this problem temporarily by switching to root user. For this;

```
sudo su
```

Become root by doing it. Then you will need to add your git config settings here as well as you are migrating to a different user. For this too

```
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Your Name"
```

and then
repeat your action again.
it should work

Answer (score 0):

I've ran the similar issue and was able to fix it on server side. git runs there under uwsgi so I added in uwsgi config the following line:

```
env = HOME=/srv/git
```

where /srv/git is owned by the same uid that uwsgi runs under and made `chmod u+rwX /srv/git`
So, you need to point HOME variable on server side for the process that runs git to the directory where this process will have reading/writing/traverse permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, it may be a case when some process like CMD or SSH client opened some folder which Git tries to delete.