# unable to access '/Users/dida/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied

Tags: git, permissions

When I do some git operations, such as '`git diff`' or '`git add .`', it shows that warning:

```
unable to access '/Users/dida/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```

I wonder which config I did wrong  and how can I fix it?
It's better with some commands, I am using mac command line

Comment: I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes/47995027#47995027) and this answer working for me

Answer (score 25):

Seems you've run `sudo -H` and sudo changed the ownership of some files to `root`. Take the files back:

```
sudo chown -R dida /Users/dida
```

Comment: I', not an experienced user in Mac and I'm think that "dida" is a command line word . don't take my mistake . in my case that's :       sudo chown -R hamid /Users/hamid

Comment: `sudo chown -R <username> /Users/<username>/.config` For me, I only wanted to include the .config folder and all its contents. Otherwise, the permissions apply to everything in the user folder which might be okay but is more coverage than this git error was indicating necessary.

Answer (score 7):

**Cause**

Git reads config settings from a variety of paths and the  doesn't have access to some of them.

Git tries to read root config setting instead of  config settings due to the starting script using su command with do not reset environment variables option (-m):

```
/bin/su -m $USER -c "cd $BASE/logs && $BASE/bin/startup.sh &> /dev/null"
```

Bitbucket Server is being started as root with /etc/init.d/atlbitbucket start script. Since the init.d script calls start-bitbucket.sh which uses su -m this causes the environment variables for root to be preserved and atlbitbucket does not have permission to write in the root home directory.

Git was compiled from source using the default settings which prevents any users other than the one that compiled Git from running it

**Resolution**

Fix the permissions on the files and directories with regard to the Bitbucket Server user performing the command:

```
chown <USER>.<GROUP> -R /home/<USER>/.config
chown <USER>.<GROUP> -R /home/<USER>/.gitconfig
```

(info) Change the USER.GROUP by your username and group in your OS.

If Bitbucket Server starting script have su command, make sure that the option -m is not used.

If Bitbucket Server is being started with /etc/init.d/atlbitbucket start switch to starting Bitbucket Servering with service atlbitbucket start

To have Bitbucket Server automatically start at boot, run chkconfig atlbitbucket on

Recompile Git using more sensible defaults:

```
make prefix=/usr/local/git all
make prefix=/usr/local/git install
```

or maybe this articles could help you https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/permission-denied-on-git-config-file-779171763.html

Comment: What works for me is as look like this: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /Users/username/.config`, and the inaccessible directory `.config` can be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

git uses the `HOME` and `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment settings to lookup the config files.

Make sure they are set properly, to your current user (check the result of the [`id` command](https://ss64.com/osx/id.html))

```
id -a
```

Check also `git config -l --show-origin` to see *where* Git is trying to access those config files.

Answer (score 1):

Upon finding out more information on the file, I noticed the file was not owned by my user("ubuntu"), but by "root" instead.

`ls -dl /home/$USER/.config` to find out the user and group of the file

---

`sudo chown $USER -R /home/$USER/.config` to update the user of the file
`sudo chgrp $USER -R home/$USER/.config/` to update the group of the file to the your current user

Now, when you get the file details using `ls` again, you'll see the information was updated.

*That fixed it for me.*

Answer (score -1):

try sudo -u user --set-home git clone http://github.com/repohere
this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

warning: unable to access '/Users/raavan/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/Users/raavan/.config/git/attributes': Permission den

ok! if you had something similar, this is the solution.
use sudo command

sudo git add --all,
sudo git commit -m ""

this will work and worked for me in mac os.

if anyone knows why the sudo command worked or alternative way please respond!.