# Xcode Can't Commit Files to Github

Tags: xcode, git

I am trying to commit to my local repository but it keeps saying "The working copy “Project” failed to commit files. 
warning: unable to access '/Users/me/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied"

I tried this [Unable to access 'git/attributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes)
It worked for a while but after about an hour of working on my project the error comes back.

I don't know if this is related but some storyboard files are randomly marked for Deletion (with the D beside their file name) when trying to commit.

Answer (score 1):

Sicne that [`.config` folder is supposed to be owned by the user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320682/ownership-of-the-config-folder-in-home-directory), check, whenever you see again this error:

- the new owner of that `.config` folder (to see of it is root)
- the process running at that time (like a [local BitBucket server running as root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49622690/6309)),
- or your command history (to see if it involved a command like `sudo htop`)