# Xcode 9.1 source control: failed to load revisions

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, xcode9

I'm using Xcode Version 9.1 (9B55), and it appears that my Comparison Editor is broken. I'm using Git in my project. When I try to turn Comparison Editor on I get following error:

`The source control operation failed because the revision “XXXXX” could not be found.`

Here is the screenshot of the Xcode interface:

[image]

My question is: has anyone of you experienced that and solved it? If so, what is the solution?

Answering possible comments in advance:
Git from command line is working as usual, I don't have any external source control editor open while trying to open comparison editor.

Comment: Has your network environment changed at all? XCode gets weird for me when I am not on my home network (in relation to git). I sometimes have to VPN do do anything with it.

Comment: nope, it didn't change.

Comment: What if you change the file in Xcode, and then use `git status` in terminal and check if the terminal can detect the changes?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT with git command line everything works as expected. Thing is that I'm usually using command line only, it's just that assistance editor is convenient to view old changes. After all, this is not something affecting development, I just wanted to verify out of curiosity if this is happening to others as well.

Comment: I'm using xcode 8.2, and has no such issue.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 9.4.1 and this issue still occurs.

Comment: I am on Xcode 11, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue myself.
For me, what worked was trying to commit a file via Xcode's source control menu.
When I tried to do that, I came across an error saying it was unable to access the git/attributes file on the `.config` folder on my Mac's user's folder since the permissions were insufficient (have no idea why it changed all of the sudden).

Bottom line: This helped me:
[Unable to access 'git/attributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!