# yarn error "EACCESS: permission denied, scandir '/home/ubuntu/.config/yarn/link'"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

Whenever I try something with yarn on Ubuntu 16.04 server.

It gives an error.

I am currently using nodejs v8.10.0

```
yarn install v1.5.1
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/ubuntu/.config/yarn/link'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/ubuntu/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It's likely a unix permission related problem. There is a solution posted on the dev's github page. Try to run the following command

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Reference: [EACCES: permission denied .config/configstore/bower-github.json #2262](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262)

Comment: Worked! used on ~/.yarn

Comment: 2 years later, same problem. Nothing works. Even this. That npm and js in general are awesome.

Comment: I had to `chown` some `.cache` and `.temp` folders inside the project. I did this - `sudo find . -type d -name '.cache' -or -name '.temp' -exec chown -R $USER:$GROUP -- {} \+;`

Comment: Super helpful answer, thank you. In my case I had run "sudo yarn install" so root owned my node_modules directory. I deleted node_modules directory then reran "yarn install" so that I was the owner and "yarn link" worked.

Comment: Im tying to run with root user and thats not works. Whem i run without root user that wroks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, I found on another thread that my config folder was owned by root, which created several permissions issues.. I changed owner to my user and this error went away.

See top answer on this thread 
[Unable to access 'git/attributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes)