# react native async storage is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a new app of react native as explained into new documentation of react native 0.61 they mentioned that to remove react-native CLI because it is creating issues....see below image: [image: image from react-native documentation 0.61]

But now I'm trying to add async storage from `yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage`
And this is giving me an error. it is not adding to my project.

I'm not getting any error in installing package but it is not adding in package.json file I also tried to add native-base then I ran react-native link that aslo not added to package.json and it also gave me error:

- warn Package @react-native-community/async-storage has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/async-storage/package.json'
- error EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/ajay/project/newEON/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/r/com'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Does it occurs with another dependency? What is the error?

Comment: Can you post error logs here, it will be easy to get to the answer.

Comment: I'm not getting any error in installing package but it is not adding in package.json file
I also tried to add native-base then I ran ```react-native link``` that aslo not added to package.json and it also gave me error:
warn Package @react-native-community/async-storage has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/async-storage/package.json'
error EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/ajay/project/newEON/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/r/com'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: Check [yarn error eaccess permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529696/yarn-error-eaccess-permission-denied-scandir-home-ubuntu-config-yarn-link) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276556/how-can-i-solve-permission-denied-in-react-native-project)

Comment: @awran5 no it's not working

Comment: @AjaySharma Whats your OS?

Comment: OS: ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that your project folder path is `/home/ajay/project/newEON/`

**1. First thing please run permission check:**

Go inside your project folder if you're not already and run:

```c
ls -l
```

You should see something like:

```c
drwxr-xr-x 1 YourUser [size] [date] node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 YourUser [size] [date] package.json
```

**If not, run:**

```c
sudo chmod -R 755 home/ajay/project/newEON/
```

Learn more about permission [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Viewing_permissions) | [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

**2. Try to remove the** `build` **folder inside** `newEON/android`

```c
// Make sure you are inside your project
rm -R android/app/build
```

**3. Try to remove** `node_modules` **and** `yarn.lock`

```c
// Make sure you are inside your project
rm -R node_modules && rm yarn.lock
```

Finally make sure you have yarn v1.xx `yarn -v`, yarn [v2](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/migration) is very different from the v1.

```
// Run after removing node_modules && rm yarn.lock
yarn
```