# Getting <user>/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied, but /git doesn't exist

Tags: git

I am setting up a Snips server on Ubuntu 18.04.1. When I try to install a skill I get this message but it doesn't happen when I git clone.

> warning: unable to access `/home/<user>/.config/git/attributes`:
>   Permission denied

I went to check the permissions for /git/ and found that the /.config/git directory doesn't exist.

I cloned a repo thinking it might create the /git directory but it didn't.

I created the /git/ folder and got the same message

I also did: `touch attributes` and the error persisted.

I checked root/.config as recommended in another similar question but there is no .config in /root

I tried `git config -l --show-origin` but I got no results

Is this a problem or can I safely ignore it?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does the Snips server run under user `<user>` or a different user? In the latter case it certainly doesn't have access to `/home/<user>/`.

Comment: I'm not sure which user the skill install is running under.
I have a feeling it's running under my user as later on during the install it can't create the venv directory as it doesn't have the required permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Check the permission of `~/.config` directory. It may have incorrectly been set to `root` if you previously ran a command with `sudo` that created the `~/.config` dir (such as `sudo htop`).

```sh
ls -ld ~/.config

# if the owner is root, then change the owner to your user
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes/47995027#47995027)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

For this go to terminal

just run command :
sudo chmod 755 /Users/your-username/.config

in your case:
sudo chmod 755 /home/your-username/.config