# Git Hub Cloning II Fatal - Repository Not Found

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am a new to learning and trying to clone GitHub for the first time and I got the below error.

***fatal: repository 'https://akbersamnani.github.io/coursera-test/' not found***

What could be the issue? and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to clone the repository to your computer you need to use

```
git clone https://github.com/akbersamnani/coursera-test.git
```

in your terminal. You also need to have git installed, you can find installation instructions e.g. from [github](https://github.com/git-guides/install-git).

You somehow managed to get an URL for a github page.

Comment: Hi Jonas - Thanks for kind help. It worked however now it is showing below permission error- unable to access '/Users/akbersamnani/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied

Comment: It will be kind if you can guide about this next issue. Appreciate your gesture.

Comment: It seems you have no permission to access your git configuration. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes) might be a similar issue.