# Permission denied .config/git/attributes error when trying to push to github

Tags: git, permissions, push, permission-denied

Trying to push git files to github.  It seems to add and commit files okay, but when I push I get this error. Not sure what is happening.  I have done the sudo ch 755 command and am getting no such directory.  I am very new to coding and am unclear on what is happening.  I am on a mac os big sure.  unable to access '/Users/lauraroblee/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied

Comment: `the sudo ch 755 command` What command are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question:

- [Unable to access 'git/attributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150926/unable-to-access-git-attributes) (top answer)

tldr: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) .config`
but I would recommend reading the full answer first to see if this is the same problem

If guess you mean you did chmod 755, that changes the permissions for the file (who gets to read, write or execute it)
In this case you want to change the ownership of the file, basically so the computer knows you are the owner of the file so you have the permission to access it.